# fluent-ffmpeg generating incorrect framerate

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-conversion, node-modules

I'm having a strange issue converting images to a video. I am using the [excellent fluent-ffmpeg module](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) for a node.js server. I have 179 jpg images which I wish to convert to a 30fps video (should be about 6s).  I have successfully done so using the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i frame%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

This outputs the following when inspected by ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 00:00:06.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1631 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1627 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
       handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Now, I am attempting to do the same thing with fluent-ffmpeg:

```
var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: 'frame%03d.jpg', nolog: true })
  .addOptions(['-c:v libx264','-r 30'])
  .saveToFile('test.mp4', function(retcode, error){
    console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
  });
```

Should be exactly the same, right?  But here is what I'm getting:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
  Duration: 00:00:07.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1556 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1553 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Now what's most interesting here is that although both were made from the same set of images and both supposedly have the same frame rate, the one made with fluent-ffmpeg has a duration of 7.20s, a full 1.20 longer than the first one.  Upon comparing the two videos, it seems the fluent-ffmpeg one is actually at 25fps even though it reports 30.

Note that I have tried properly adding the two flags using the methods (`.withVideoCodec, .withFps`) with the same result, I merely resorted to adding the arguments manually in an attempt to make it exactly the same as my original command.

If anybody here has experience with this module and/or has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and found out that you need to specify Input FPS to match your image sequence source.

```
.withFpsInput(30) // fps matching your jpg or png input sequence
```

This worked great for me. Hope it helps!